# Disable logging with hibernate from maven

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, configuration, log4j

I have recently added hibernate to my pom.xml, and it is working fine. However, the logging is irritating and i'm not sure how to turn it off or limit the level of it (I don't even know exactly what it has included to start all this logging). I am new to this, to maven and to hibernate.

Here is my pom.xml dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
        <classifier>tests</classifier>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.10</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

The log starts like this:

```
21:17:15.115 [main] DEBUG org.jboss.logging - Logging Provider: org.jboss.logging.Slf4jLoggerProvider
21:17:15.130 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration boolean -> org.hibernate.type.BooleanType@ba4d54
21:17:15.130 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration boolean -> org.hibernate.type.BooleanType@ba4d54
21:17:15.130 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration java.lang.Boolean -> org.hibernate.type.BooleanType@ba4d54
```

I have tried adding a log4j.properties file to my resources and it didn't seem to change anything. I also tried simplelog.properties (following other SO posts which haven't helped). I'm a bit stuck here, help would be really appreciated. Ideally, i'd like to just set the logger to off, or just the mysql queries.

This is the dependency tree:

```
    [INFO] org.springframework:gs-rest-service:jar:0.1.0
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:1.1.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:1.1.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:1.1.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:1.1.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:1.1.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.13:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:1.1.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:7.0.57:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:7.0.57:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-logging-juli:jar:7.0.57:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:7.0.57:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.3.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.3.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.3.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.0.3.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.0.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.0.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.0.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.0.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.0.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.0.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.0.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:4.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:jar:1.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.1.0.CR2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.18.1-GA:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:4.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:tests:4.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] \- mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.10:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 35.918 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-02-07T22:09:37+00:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 20M/203M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have a global `DEBUG` log level set in your logging framework configuration.

All you need to do is setting the `org.hibernate` log level to `WARN` or `ERROR` instead:

- Logback/Log4j2

  ```
  <logger name="org.hibernate" level="warn"/>
  ```
- Log4j

  ```
  <logger name="org.hibernate">
     <level value="warn"/> 
  </logger>
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't know where I can find the logging framework configuration, I think this is the problem. Any hints? Since I have created no configuration files, I am guessing this is a default, or something packaged within one of the jars which maven retrieved.

Comment: You need to run `mvn dependency:tree` and check for log4j and logback. The bets way to override some default log config is to add your own configuration in `src/main/resources`.

Comment: Ok, I can see this in my tree:
[INFO] |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.1.2:compile

I assume this means I am using logback (I am not entirely sure what this is), therefore I need your first bit of code <logger name="org.hibernate" level="warn"/>

I'll create a configuration file with that in inside src/main/resources (looking up naming etc now)

Comment: How can I do it the in the log4j2.properties file?