# adding jXLS to my pom.xml seems to affect hibernate log level

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, tomcat, jxls

Adding jXLS to my pom seems to affect my app Hibernate log level. The app will log hibernate DEBUG info at every second in the tomcat console (using eclipse).

I add these two dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jxls</groupId>
        <artifactId>jxls</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jxls</groupId>
        <artifactId>jxls-jexcel</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

When I remove both, then everything will be ok. If I add any of them, then I get the DEBUG info in the console again.

Any idea why is this happening?! Logger is Log4j.

Comment: may you could have added in log4j properties those dependencies package. if you don't want remove from the logger properties

Answer (score 2):

I found an answer in this post:

[Disable logging with hibernate from maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28387553/disable-logging-with-hibernate-from-maven)

Adding file logback.xml with the described content solved hibernate logging problem.